# set background for wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I have a background image template

[image]

where header and footer is in the template image
I just want to render content in content area

how to achieve this?

I tried to separate the header and footer html
and my code sample is
my php code is

```
$html = view('products.pdf.index', compact('product'))->render();

    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)
        ->setPaper('a4')
        ->setOrientation('portrait')
        ->setOption('header-spacing', 0)
        ->setOption('footer-spacing', 0)
        ->setOption('header-html', view('products.pdf.header')->render())
        ->setOption('footer-html', view('products.pdf.footer')->render())
        ->setOption('margin-top', 10)
        ->setOption('margin-right', 0)
        ->setOption('margin-bottom', 18)
        ->setOption('margin-left', 0);
    return $pdf->download($product->title . '.pdf');
```

where in header(products.pdf.header) file I have header content and in footer(products.pdf.footer) file I have footer content, `$html` holds my content

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Be clear and show what you have tried so far?

Comment: first I seprated the header html and footer html but on page break I am not able to manage margin for content area. My content sticks right next to header. that I dont want

Comment: Please show us your code, then you will be following the guidelines for posting a question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I need the way to achieve this problem. where on automatic page break content should be in content area. but right now its in next line of header I need to manage spacing between header and content